# VBA Excel unforeseen changes of buttons when code is executed

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have the following code:

```
Sub code_clearance_cable()
Dim ws As Worksheet, dict
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
Dim key As String
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xRng1 As Range

Dim fso, ts
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("debug.txt")

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cable Work Order")
Set xRng1 = ws.Columns("H")
With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
         If Len(Trim(.Cells(i, "H"))) = 0 Then
            key = Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
            If dict.exists(key) Then
               .Rows(i).Delete
               n = n + 1
            Else
               dict.Add key, i
            End If
        Else
            key = ""
        End If
        ts.writeline i & " A='" & .Cells(i, "A") & "' H='" _
            & .Cells(i, "H") & "' key='" & key & "' n=" & n
     Next
  End With
  ts.Close

 End Sub
```

which change the size and location of my buttons despite their settings - **don't move and size with cells**

[image]

It happens only when I close down the document. After opening it again it comes out with the situation as shown in the image.

Is it something I could do with it programmatically? All of them are form controls.

It behaves the same for ActiveX buttons

[image]

Comment: The simplest way is to try ActiveX buttons...

Comment: They don't work either